# qTip2 Change calling element's background color while open

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm just curious if anyone knows how to do this.  Basically I have a big table and each td has a qtip with an embedded table that provides more info.  I would like for the td's background color to change to match the qtip so the user knows that is the particular cell they are viewing.  Here is the JS for my qtip:

```
            $('.resultCell').each(function(){
                $(this).qtip({
                    content: {
                        text:$('table',this)
                    },
                    position: {
                        my: 'top center',
                        at: 'bottom center'
                    },
                    hide: {
                        fixed: true,
                        delay: 500
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Maybe something along these lines? var color = $(this).qtip.css("background-color");
$(this).css("background-color", color);

Comment: @ZackMacomber I've got that much figured out, but I don't know how to actually make the change.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to change the content and your other settings, but this Code will highlight the `td` which shows the actual tooltip.

**See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/9eUGQ/) and code below:**

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("td").each(function() {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: "Test IT"
            },
            position: {
                my: 'top center',
                at: 'bottom center'
            },
            events: {
                show: function(event, api) {
                    api.elements.target.addClass("active");
                },
                hide: function(event, api) {
                    api.elements.target.removeClass("active");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

#### HTML

```
<table>
  <tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td></tr>
  <tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td></tr>
  <tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td></tr>
  <tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td></tr>
  <tr><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td><td>XXX</td></tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
td {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    padding:5px;
}
table {
    margin: 20px;
}
.active {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

​